# Problem with "ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead"

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scikit-learn, regression

I need to run a SVR (supported vector regression). I have a CSV data frame.I had no problems to run the OLS regression, with one target variable and multiple regressors. But I have a problem with this part of the code.

So, here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.svm import SVR

sc_X = StandardScaler()
sc_y = StandardScaler()
X = sc_X.fit_transform(X)
y = sc_y.fit_transform(y)

y_pred = sc_y.inverse_transform ((regressor.predict (sc_X.transform(np.array([[6.5]])))))
plt.scatter(X, y, color = 'magenta')
plt.plot(X, regressor.predict(X))
plt.title('SVR')
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('VF')
plt.show()

X_grid = np.arange(min(X), max(X), 0.1)
X_grid = X_grid.reshape((len(X_grid), 1))
plt.scatter(X, y)
plt.plot(X_grid, regressor.predict(X_grid))
plt.title('SVR')
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('VF')
plt.show()
```

I have the following error message:"ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead 
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample."

It's the first time I encounter this problem. I saw in other topic that is not scarce, but in fact i don't understand where to reshape the data in my code. When i tried to do it, it says that DataFrame has no reshape function.

Here is a pic of my dataset. The target is VF, all the other variables are the regressors. [image: my dataset]

Thanks,

Comment: post some data to reproduce this

Comment: I put a picture of my dataset in order to show you the structure. It's a big one, with more than 25.000 values.

Comment: what does `X.shape` return?

Comment: It returns (14085, 8). I made a mistake on the comment above, I have 14085 observations.

Comment: `np.arange(min(X), max(X), 0.1)` returns a 1D array, not a 2D one.

Comment: Thanks for your help. How can I modify that to get an 2D array ?

Comment: Where does this error occur?  Is it one of the `fit_transform` lines?  Tell us about the `X` (or `Y`).  If you want real help, give real information, not vague stuff.

Comment: Yes, the first error occurs at the line regressor.fit(x,y). I created now 1 CSV with my 3 regressors, and 1 CSV with my target, and run the code again. But I have another error message: bad input shape (14085, 2).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that when you do:

```
 X = sc_X.fit_transform(X)
```

X contains more than one variables. 8 to be specific

Next you do:

```
 regressor.predict(sc_X.transform(np.array([[6.5]])))
```

Now you try to transform a new sample that has only one variable but the `sc` model was trained on data with more than one variable.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the point. How can I fix the problem then ?

Comment: you have to define a sample that has also 8 features, or fit the `sc` model using only one variable from X

Comment: After modifying the code, I have this new error message : non-broadcastable output operand with shape (1,1) doesn't match the broadcast shape (1,2)